# Visit a variant with a monostate

Tags: c++, variant, visitor-pattern

I am having trouble wrapping my head around variant.

I read, that I can use std::monostate to imply an empty state as one of the alternatives inside the variant. However, how do I then use the visitor pattern that is facilitated with std::visit?

```
#include <variant>


struct Visitor{
  void operator()(double){};
  void operator()(int){};
};

int main() {
  std::variant<std::monostate, int, double> v = 1;

  std::visit(Visitor{}, v);
}
```

does not work and neither does providing an call-operator overload for std::monostate .

If I try to include a universal reference overload for the call operator, it just matches everything and does not use the two specific overloads anymore

Comment: can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/GAPn3v

Answer (score 6):

I added proper visitor method and it works for me on https://wandbox.org/ c++2a

What was your problem with it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>


struct Visitor{
  void operator()(double){ std::cout << "Double!" << std::endl; };
  void operator()(int){ std::cout << "Int!" << std::endl; };

  // that was missing:
  void operator()(std::monostate){ std::cout << "Mono!" << std::endl; };
};

int main() {
  std::variant<std::monostate, int, double> v = 1;
  std::variant<std::monostate, int, double> w;

  std::visit(Visitor{}, v);
  std::visit(Visitor{}, w);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> does not work and neither does providing an call-operator overload for std::monostate.

The additional overload on `std::monostate` does work for me:

```
struct Visitor {
   void operator()(double){}
   void operator()(int){}
   void operator()(std::monostate){}
};
```

When used like this

```
std::variant<std::monostate, int, double> v = 1;
std::visit(Visitor{}, v); // invokes the int overload

v= 1.234;
std::visit(Visitor{}, v); // ... and the double overload

v = std::monostate{};
std::visit(Visitor{}, v); // ... and finally the std::monostate overload
```

it should happily compile and yield the expected behavior.

Comment: it does, strange, maybe I was to tired yesterday evening. Thank you guys a lot.